# Inverse cascade challenge - Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

> Print the following pattern, when you invoke `inverse_cascade(1234)`
>
> ```
> 1
> 12
> 123
> 1234
> 123
> 12
> 1
> ```

**Solution:**

```
def inverse_cascade(n):
    def grow(n):
        if n < 10:
            print(n)
        else:
            grow(n // 10)
            print(n)
    def shrink(n):
        if n < 10:
            print(n)
        else:
            print(n)
            shrink(n // 10)
    grow(n // 10)
    print(n)
    shrink(n // 10)
```

Using a recursion approach, how can I improve this code without using higher order functions?

**Note:** No data models have to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Separate `grow` and `shrink` functions are not necessary. Instead you can have a single function that prints, recurses and prints again the same value when the recursion returns.

For example like this:

```
def inverse_cascade(n, digits=1):
    n = str(n)
    print(n[:digits])
    if digits < len(n):
        inverse_cascade(n, digits+1)
        print(n[:digits])
```

Answer (score 2):

In `grow()`:

> ```
>     if n < 10:
>         print(n)
>     else:
>         grow(n // 10)
>         print(n)
> ```

`print(n)` is called in any case, so this can be simplified to

```
    if n >= 10:
        grow(n // 10)
    print(n)
```

The same applies to the `shrink()` function.

And in

> ```
> grow(n // 10)
> print(n)
> shrink(n // 10)
> ```

the `print(n)` can be eliminated by calling either `grow()` or
`shrink()` with `n` instead of `n \\ 10`.

Also your code produces three output lines for a single-digit
input because `grow(n // 10)` and `shrink(n // 10)` is called even
if `n < 10`.

Together:

```
def inverse_cascade(n):
    def grow(n):
        if n >= 10:
            grow(n // 10)
        print(n)
    def shrink(n):
        print(n)
        if n >= 10:
            shrink(n // 10)
    grow(n)
    if n >= 10:
        shrink(n // 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

DRY your code.  Don't Repeat yourself by having each branch do a `print()`.  Pull it out and branch based on the recursive condition. (As Martin R has mentioned)

*EDIT: OP's Question was changed such that the number is known ahead of time.  Will leave the rest, but it isn't applicable to the OP's edit.*

```
grow(n // 10)
print(n)
shrink(n // 10)
```

This works fine if you have a number you want to grow/shrink.  However, you could generate the value 1234 based off the current level of recursion you are at.

```
def inverse_cascade(max_level, level=1, value=0):
    value = value * 10 + level
    print(value)

    if max_level != level:
        cascade(max_level, level + 1, value)
        print(value)
```